# Cookies not saving when being set from json response

Tags: node.js, remix.run

I am trying to save the access_token and refresh_token of a user after oAuth.

Flow:

- User authenticates and I retrieve their accessToken, refreshToken, and user data from the social site
- I send data to a remix resource route
- In the action for the remix-resource route, I save the data and then try to set the access token and refresh token using 'Set-Cookie' but it doesn't work.

Including the relevant part of my /api/setUser resource route where I try to set the cookie

```
export let action: ActionFunction = async ({ request }) => {
    const session = await sessionStorage.getSession(
        request.headers.get('Cookie')
    );
    const jsonData = await request.json();
    session.set('access_token', jsonData['accessToken']);
    session.set('refresh_token', jsonData['refreshToken']);

    return json<LoaderData>(
        { status: 'ok' },
        {
            headers: {
                'Set-Cookie': await sessionStorage.commitSession(session),
            },
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: The session management looks good to me. Maybe it is the createCookieSessionStorage configs. Once I got stuck because of the domain props at the cookie wasn't right.

Comment: Do you have a particular error ?
NB : If cookie is more than 4kb (access token can be huge depending what data it has) it'll throw an error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your `createCookieSessionStorage` that you have the cookie path set to `/` otherwise, the cookie is only visible on the route you set it.